# PHP get last insert id in first query and execute it on second query with multi row

Tags: php, mysql

I need help. I have a problem using multi query I want to put the last insert id in the next query the problem is it only adds one. Cart_id and qty has a multiple row. Please i need help thanks in advance.

Here is my code:

```
 public function insertOrder($cart_id = null,$qty = null)
{
    if (isset($cart_id)) {

        $query = "INSERT INTO `tblsales`(`user_id`, `status`) VALUES ('23','delivery');";
        $last_id = $this->db->con->insert_id;
        $query .= "INSERT INTO `tblorders`(`sales_id`,`product_id`, `quantity`) VALUES ($last_id, {$cart_id},{$qty});";

        $result = $this->db->con->multi_query($query);
        if ($result) {
            header("Location :" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Parameters inserting multiple values in each row

```
if (isset($_POST['cartid']) && $_POST['qty']){
foreach ($_POST["cartid"] AS $key => $item){     
$result = $product->insertOrder($_POST['cartid'][$key], $_POST['qty'][$key]);
echo json_encode($result);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Tried you injecting a sql SELECT query between two insert methods?

```
public function insertOrder($cart_id = null,$qty = null){
  if (isset($cart_id)) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO `tblsales`(`user_id`, `status`) VALUES ('23','delivery');";
    $last_id = getLastId("tablename");
    $query .= "INSERT INTO `tblorders`(`sales_id`,`product_id`, `quantity`) VALUES ($last_id, {$cart_id},{$qty});";

    $result = $this->db->con->multi_query($query);
    if ($result) {
        header("Location :" . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }
    return $result;
  }
}
```

Get last id function:

```
function getLastId($tablename){
$sql = "SELECT id FROM $tablename ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
//any necessary method, and $id = get sql result
return $id;
}
```

Comment: Is it ok if i'm going to the ID at the same time insert it on the table?

Comment: Yes, your code use more steps. 
First step: Insert data to tblsales // if true go to the next step
2. step: Get first step id.
3. step: Insert data to tblorders.

This is the only solution for this operation, because when you first insert the data into the mysql database, the id is created. It cannot be requested in advance because it may result in a security risk.

Comment: Suppose you deleted a row and you add one to the previous record id, but the next id really will be more by two. This is a mistake.

Comment: I got this error why? Undefined function 'getLastId'  this is my code :  public function getLastId($table = 'tblsales')
    {
        if ($this->db->con != null) {

            $query = "SELECT id FROM {$table} ORDER BY sales_id DESC LIMIT 1";

            $result = $this->db->con->query($query);
          
            return $result;
        }
    }

Comment: yes i will got problem with that .. when i deleted it will comeback to previous id and i got a trouble in my records

Comment: Is it possible you to call the function wrong? ($this->getLastId()).

Comment: The function is ok now... I'm trying to do your suggestion but it doesn't  work...